# How can i directed to the next chapter on restart of the application?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
    FIRST PAGE
    package com.example.ntpage;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class FirstpageActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.firstpage);
            final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chp1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(FirstpageActivity.this, Secondform.class));
                }
            });


    }
    SECOND PAGE
    package com.example.ntpage;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Secondform extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondform);
            final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Secondform.this, Thirdform.class));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondform, menu);
            return true;enter code here
        }

    }

package com.example.ntpage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Thirdform extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thirdform);
        final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Thirdform.this, Forthform.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.thirdform, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

//This is the scenarion when i go to the firstpage then click chapter1
it will proceed to the chapter2 when i click  thats means the save point of my chapter is at
2 when i restart the system it will not go for the chapte1 it will go direct at chapter2

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at storage options in the developers guide of Android. Seems this is a job for shared preferences

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html